# How to get internal persistent data path?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When a phone has SD-card

```
Application.persistentDataPath
```

returns path like

```
/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.company.product/files
```

and when a phone has no SD-card, it returns

```
/data/data/com.company.product/files
```

But how do I get the second path when a phone has SD-card?

Comment: I guess you have only one persistent path based on your install location (internal/external)

Comment: but what if someone has installed an app on a phone without SD-card, then the app created some files in persistent data folder, and after that the owner of the phone has inserted a SD-card into the phone? the persistent data path will be another in this case

Comment: Use `getFilesDir()`. and `getExternalFilesDir()` instead.

Comment: Take a look at this thread on Unity Answers: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/283823/how-can-you-save-both-internally-and-externally.html#answer-1156955